# How to pack a struct with a struct member in lua?

Tags: struct, lua

I'm writing a lua script for Nginx to communicate with a server which provides a protocol I must comply with. And the protocol accepts a struct with a struct member, I can't find a way to pack it in lua.

```
require "struct"
-- struct udp_packet_header {
--     uint32_t head_token;
--     uint64_t uuid;
--     uint64_t timestamp;
--     uint32_t order;
--     uint32_t trans_size;
--     uint32_t https_size;
--     uint16_t head_crc;
-- };
local udp_packet_header_def = '<ILLIIIH'

-- struct udp_packet {
--     struct udp_packet_header header;
--     char data[];
-- };
local udp_packet_struct_def = ?
```

As defined above, how can I pack the struct `udp_packet` with a struct member `header`?

I checked https://github.com/iryont/lua-struct but found nothing useful.

Is doing this even possible? If not, is there a better way to do this? Maybe write C code and call it from lua?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/support/

Comment: beside that you should prefer the support of commercial products over StackOverflow it would help if you would provide more useful information. for example a link to the respective documentation and the function you want to put that data container into...

Comment: @Piglet You must have misunderstood my question, there are nothing to do with Nginx, I mentioned Nginx just to elaborate the background, you can just leave the Nginx part and the question can be described as `how can I use the lua package struct to pack a struct with a struct member`. And I don't quite agree with your opinion, Nginx itself provides two kinds of services, one for open source and one for commercial, as an open source user, I can ask question about it in SO, if every one goes to commercial support, then SO would have no meaning to exist.